# How to query only 1 ID out of multiple rows and choose based on the maximum date with amazon redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, partition-by

I have this data structure in my table. One row represents 1 date and 1 status

```
id    date             status
1     2022-02-12         in
1     2022-02-13         out
1     2022-02-14         dlv
2     2022-02-13         in
2     2022-02-14         out
2     2022-02-15         dlv
```

From this table, I want to get the maximum date in which before or equal to `2022-02-14` and also the status for each row. The desired result:

```
id    date             status
1     2022-02-14         dlv
2     2022-02-14         out
```

What I have done is:

```
select distinct id, date, status
from table1
where date <= ('2022-02-14')
group by date, status
order by date desc limit 1
```

But this query only gives one `id` out of 100 `id` I have in my table.

Can somebody help me how to get the desired table?

I use aws redshift for this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is there no record for `in` in your expected output?

Comment: because I want to get only 1 status for each row which the maximum date is before or equal to 2022-02-14. The ```in``` record is at 2022-02-12 and 2022-02-13

Comment: What would be wrong with `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date = '2022-02-14'` ?

Comment: there are also some ```id``` where the maximum date is before 2022-02-14. I also need to capture it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER for this type of query.  Order the rows by date descending and find the row with the lowest number for each id.  Like so:

```
with row_order as (
  select id, date, status, row_number() over(partition by id order by date 
  descending) as rn
  from table1
  where date <= ('2022-02-14')
)
select id, date, status
from row_order
where rn = 1;
```